# Outlook Add In, Audit when a mail read for the first time

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I have put together the following code to write an event when some one reads their mail. But i need to write only when it is read the first time. Any ideas on how to achieve this.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
            inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
            application = new Outlook.Application();
            oINS = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        }

void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {
            currentItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            currentItem.Read += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReadEventHandler(item_read);

        }

void item_read()
        {
            WriteAudit("Item being read newly");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the following line of code:

```
 application = new Outlook.Application();
```

There is no need to create a new Application instance in the `Startup` event handler. Instead, you can use the Application property of the add-in class.

In that case you need to keep the list of unread items IDs for checking whether a mail item was opened earlier or not.

But there is a simpler solution. Handle the [PropertyChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866739.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the MailItem class which is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, Subject) of an instance of the parent object is changed. You are interested in the [UnRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868556.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property changes. The property returns a Boolean value that is True if the Outlook item has not been opened (read).